# Naming a JSON array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have an array of JSON:

```
 [{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225?v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/8931462?v=4","Name":"aws-microservices-deploy-options","Score":20.521696,"Updatedat":"2018-07-20T12:22:07Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/4046529?v=4","Name":"useful-jenkins-groovy-init-scripts","Score":21.447626,"Updatedat":"2018-07-18T19:52:02Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6755615?v=4","Name":"dnsjava","Score":34.74705,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T15:16:45Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/504773?v=4","Name":"luke","Score":19.239859,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T07:27:26Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/536912?v=4","Name":"Wicket-tutorial-examples","Score":37.265644,"Updatedat":"2018-07-14T04:28:50Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/33330803?v=4","Name":"nexus-repository-apt","Score":44.401646,"Updatedat":"2018-07-06T18:28:13Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1321963?v=4","Name":"marc4j","Score":28.282797,"Updatedat":"2018-07-07T15:58:57Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5622390?v=4","Name":"jamonapi","Score":24.564436,"Updatedat":"2018-07-16T07:44:35Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}]
```

I want it to be:

```
{ 
   gitdList: [
      {"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225? v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},   
      {"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}
   ]
}
```

I searched and am finding solutions regarding php only , to use json.encode.
How do I do it using JQUERY?

Comment: You don't need jQuery. Just `var obj = { gitdList: theArray };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try like this way? just create an empty object like this `object = {}` and **assign** your existing value i.e `avatar_urls` to it with your desired key i.e `gitdList`. Hope this will work for you.

```js
var avatar_urls = [{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225?v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/8931462?v=4","Name":"aws-microservices-deploy-options","Score":20.521696,"Updatedat":"2018-07-20T12:22:07Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/4046529?v=4","Name":"useful-jenkins-groovy-init-scripts","Score":21.447626,"Updatedat":"2018-07-18T19:52:02Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6755615?v=4","Name":"dnsjava","Score":34.74705,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T15:16:45Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/504773?v=4","Name":"luke","Score":19.239859,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T07:27:26Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/536912?v=4","Name":"Wicket-tutorial-examples","Score":37.265644,"Updatedat":"2018-07-14T04:28:50Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/33330803?v=4","Name":"nexus-repository-apt","Score":44.401646,"Updatedat":"2018-07-06T18:28:13Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1321963?v=4","Name":"marc4j","Score":28.282797,"Updatedat":"2018-07-07T15:58:57Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5622390?v=4","Name":"jamonapi","Score":24.564436,"Updatedat":"2018-07-16T07:44:35Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}]
var object = {};
object.gitdList = avatar_urls;
console.log(object);
```

**Edit:** pretty neat and better way to do it.

```
var object = { gitdList: avatar_urls};
console.log(object);
```

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna glad it helps you somehow. best of luck

Comment: *"assign"* is better description than *"push"*

Comment: @charlietfl yes of course, I agreed with you sir.thanks for suggesting. I've edited it

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this:

```js
var data=[{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225?v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/8931462?v=4","Name":"aws-microservices-deploy-options","Score":20.521696,"Updatedat":"2018-07-20T12:22:07Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/4046529?v=4","Name":"useful-jenkins-groovy-init-scripts","Score":21.447626,"Updatedat":"2018-07-18T19:52:02Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6755615?v=4","Name":"dnsjava","Score":34.74705,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T15:16:45Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/504773?v=4","Name":"luke","Score":19.239859,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T07:27:26Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/536912?v=4","Name":"Wicket-tutorial-examples","Score":37.265644,"Updatedat":"2018-07-14T04:28:50Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/33330803?v=4","Name":"nexus-repository-apt","Score":44.401646,"Updatedat":"2018-07-06T18:28:13Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1321963?v=4","Name":"marc4j","Score":28.282797,"Updatedat":"2018-07-07T15:58:57Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5622390?v=4","Name":"jamonapi","Score":24.564436,"Updatedat":"2018-07-16T07:44:35Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}];
var new_data={ 'gitdList': data };
console.log(new_data);
```